# Confused between whether or not to change the class_mode from binary to categorical in Imagedatagenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

When i shifted from 2 classes to 4 classes in a CNN model. I got errors. A lot of people helped me solve them, like I needed to change loss to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and last layer activation function.

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
)
```

I am confused as I had to change the loss function from `binary_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossenpropy`. I want to know whether I should change the class_mode from binary to categorical for 4 classes or should I leave it as binary.

```
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    #vertical_flip = True,
    validation_split=0.2,
    brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5]

)

#test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
 #   rescale=1./255,
 #   
#)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width,img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='training'
)

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir, # same directory as training data
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='validation'
    #validation_data_dir,
    #target_size=(img_width,img_height),
    #batch_size=batch_size,
    #class_mode='binary'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think reading the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) would be a good starting point. It would answer all your questions, and then some.

> **class_mode**: One of "categorical", "binary", "sparse", "input", or None. Default: "categorical". Determines the type of label arrays that are returned: - **"categorical" will be 2D one-hot encoded labels, - "binary" will be 1D binary labels**, "sparse" will be 1D integer labels, - "input" will be images identical to input images (mainly used to work with autoencoders). - If None, no labels are returned (the generator will only yield batches of image data, which is useful to use with model.predict_generator()). Please note that in case of class_mode None, the data still needs to reside in a subdirectory of directory for it to work correctly.

So you should use `categorical_crossentropy` as loss function if you choose `categorical` for `class_mode`, and `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` if you choose `sparse`.

Comment: Ok Sir Thank you. if i use sparse_categorical_crossentropy with class_mode=sparse. should i be able  to classify between 4 classes easily?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you should change it. If you have only 2 classes use `class_mode='binary'` in `flow_from_directory` function and `binary_crossentropy` as loss. In case you have more than 2 classes, use `class_mode='categorical'` and `categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: Thank you sir i did but i got this error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_84 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)

Comment: i got this error on model.fit. The code on which error occured is:
---> 38     validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,

Comment: I _guess_ this is because of the last layer of model. In the categorical  classification, last layer should have _n_ neurons (where _n_ = number of classes) and `softmax` activation

Comment: Yes Sir my outer layer is this:

model.add(Dense(numclasses)) # numclasses = 4 in your case
model.add(Activation('softmax'))